# At your fingertips

Tags: grammar

I've encountered a sentence on the internet which is from a show called Westworld. However, I have to say that I hadn't watched the episode that the sentence is taken from yet so in case you would required more information I'm afraid but I cannot provide it.
The sentence is " You have no past, because it's always present at your finger tips"
I take "present" as "in attendance" in this sentence.

However, after I contemplated over it I saw another possibility. Could there be any reduced relative clause? " You have no past, because it's always present (that is) at your finger tips". In this situation "present" would obviously mean "now". I thought this because there is a word "past" in the beginning of the sentence and then saying afterwards "present" would make a pun. Unfortunately, those both sentences doesn't make much sense to me so I couldn't find out it by interpreting merely the meaning. My first question is that would it be grammatically correct if there's reduced relative clause like I assumed? And if it is the case then which meaning makes more sense here?

Comment: "It's always now at your fingertips" doesn't sound natural, so a pun intended here would stretch the 'dire' classification. But the pun is in using 'past = history' with 'present = in attendance' so closely together. 'The present' cf 'the future', 'the past' is not all that common, but without the article it's very rare. I'd discount the suggested second reading. _The cute oxymoron is enough to get your mind around_. Is it supposed to mean that Wikipedia is now all-knowing? That imagination and reality are inseparable?

Comment: So it's not grammarly wrong but if examined its meaning "in attendance" is the one we should go with. Right?

Comment: 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' is not ungrammatical, but in line with what Orwell says, should usually be considered unacceptable. "He has a chequered past" and "She has a bright future" are idiomatic, but "He has a bright [etc] present" sound unusual to unnatural. "It's always present" instead of "It's always the present" is possibly ungrammatical. I'd take the 'in attendence' sense, but don't like the sentence; it's at least verging on the ill-formed, in trying to be clever.